# Campo do tipo decimal Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma tabela chamada Pecas onde só tem nome e valor, porem quando clico em criar nova peça não esta salvando no banco de dados, aparece a msg que foi adicionada mas nao esta inserindo, no debug mostra o nome mas o valor sempre esta chegando 0 nao importa o valor que eu coloque.

Table

```
    public class Pecas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitatio { get; set; }


}
```

TableVM

```
        public PecasVM()
    {

    }

    public PecasVM(Pecas row)
    {
        Id = row.Id;
        Nome = row.Nome;
        ValorUnitatio = row.ValorUnitatio;

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitatio { get; set; }
```

Minha controller

```
        public ActionResult Criar()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Criar(PecasVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                Pecas pec = new Pecas();

                pec.Nome = model.Nome;
                pec.ValorUnitatio = model.ValorUnitatio;

                db.Pecas.Add(pec);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }

        TempData["MSG"] = "Peça adicionada com sucesso.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Algumas dúvidas: quando vc diz valor está se referindo a `ValorUnitario`?
Se for, não pode ser erro de conversão já que o valor é `decimal`? Está passando um valor inteiro, sem vírgula/ponto? Mesmo assim com valor zerado em `ValorUnitario` deveria inserir normalmente porque zero é um valor aceitável. 
Outro ponto, como vc não está informando o valor de `Id`, imagino que ele seja `identity/sequence/auto_increment` etc no seu banco certo?

Comment: Provavelmente o json que chega esta vindo como uma string, já que ele não consegue converter, ele utiliza o valor default do decimal que é zero.

Comment: Já tentou mapear a propriedade como `double`?

Comment: Resolveu funcionar sozinho, sem eu alterar nada, tentava com virgula e ponto e não ia e agora esta inserindo.

Comment: certamente ...  if (ModelState.IsValid) se for invalido vai mostra que inseriu

Comment: @CezarMdlosci Como resolveu "sozinho", não seria melhor fechar a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
        public ActionResult Detalhes(int id)
    {


        ConsertoVM model;
        using (Db db= new Db())
        {

            decimal total = 0m;

            Conserto cons = db.Conserto.Find(id);
            decimal vPeca = cons.Pecas.ValorUnitatio;
            decimal maoObra = cons.ValorMaoObra;

            total += vPeca + maoObra;
            cons.ValorTotalConserto = total;

            model = new ConsertoVM(cons);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

claro poderia ser feito de outra maneira mas quis fazer assim.